# JVM Page Faults should be Zero, right? How High is OK?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, fault, pagefile

OK folks, this is another "I think is a stupid question", but for clarity's sake warrants appearing foolish.

In the windows task manager for a properly-configured JVM, the page fault should be Zero right? (or "top" for linux folks)

e.g., if your Xmx says "4G" and the JVM has 4G of physical RAM *available* (e.g. out of total 8G, leaving 3+G for the OS), the OS should never reach into pagefile.sys for normal jvm operations.

That's the theory. What's the practice? And if pagefaults are non-zero, what's an acceptable number?

**Monitoring Tools**

What's the best way to monitor for 'page faults too high' ?

thanks

Comment: How do you think the jvm itself, all the native libs, and all the class libraries are brought into memory?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you allocate a large amount of memory for the JVM heap, page faults can still occur. For example, if you try to load a file which is on a hard disk but not mapped into RAM a page fault occurs and the file is paged into memory.

Comment: why would java.io.File operations appear as "page faults" in the windows task manager?

Comment: @user331465: Because a page fault occurs when data is not in physical memory that needs to be. They happen all the time, including when a process is first initialized on your system.